# How to apply background image as superscript to an HTML element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

i have three circles with content. I have already given background as colors for these list items. i am trying to apply another background to second child as image. is there any better way to do it.. i tried to implement but not working out...

[image]

I use the code `<li class="active-circle">
                        <span class="bold active-circle-inner">aaa</span><br>
                        <span class="active-circle-inner">aaa</span>
                     </li>`
                    `<li class="active-circle">
                        <span class="bold active-circle-inner">bbb</span><br>
                        <span class="active-circle-inner">bbb</span>
                     </li>`
                   `<li class="active-circle">
                        <span class="bold active-circle-inner">ccc</span><br>
                        <span class="active-circle-inner">ccc</span>
                     </li>`

And the css i have is [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following Code to generate the same result.

```
<ul>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="second">
    <div class="outer-circle"></div>
</li>
<li class="third"></li></ul>
```

and the css will be

```
    ul
{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
    .first
    {
        background-color: black;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .second
    {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .third
    {
        background-color: green;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .outer-circle
    {
        background-color: black;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
        position:absolute;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: perfecto. Thanks a lot.